# How to bind jQuery events on multiple PREDECLARED jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

This is how to bind multiple events on a couple jQuery selectors:

```
$('#selector1,.selector2').bind('event', function (e, ui) {
   // Stuff
});
```

But!  How do you bind on predeclared jQuery objects.  Example:

```
var jSelector1 = $('#selector1');
var jSelector2 = $('.selector2');
```

Because, the following doesn't work:

```
jSelector1,jSelector2.bind(...);
```

nor does:

```
$jSelector1,$jSelector2.bind(...);
($jSelector1,$jSelector2).bind(...);
(jSelector1,jSelector2).bind(...);
```

Comment: and I'm not looking for jAllSelectors = $('#selector1,.selector2');

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work, assuming your variables hold jQuery objects

```
$.each([jSelector1, jSelector2], function(i,v) {

    v.bind( ... );

});
```

Answer (score 4):

you should be able to do something like this:

```
var jSelector1 = $('#selector1');
var jSelector2 = $('.selector2');

$.each([jSelector1, jSelector2], function(index, value) { 
  value.bind(....); 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use `.add()`.

```
var jSelector1 = $('#selector1'),
    jSelector2 = $('.selector2'),
    jSelector3 = $('.selector3');

jSelector1.add(jSelector2).add(jSelector3).bind('whatever', function() {
  doSomethingAwesome();
});
```